# Have buttons move div different amounts

Tags: javascript

So I have three buttons, each triggers an event. At the same time as triggering an event, i want it to move a div next to the button that was clicked. Problem is I want it not to teleport next to the button but move there in an animation. I have my code organised as shown below but it only occurs once and then when i try and click on a different button the div stays there.

```js
function func1() {
  var elem = document.getElementById("thebarofpower");
    var pos = elem.style.top;
  var doneTheStuff;
    var id = setInterval(frame, 10);
    function frame() {
  if (!doneTheStuff) {
    doneTheStuff = true;
  } else if (pos == 6) {
            clearInterval(id); 
        } else if (pos > 6) {
            pos++; 
            elem.style.top = pos - 'px';  
        } else {
          pos++;
          elem.style.top = pos + 'px';  
        }
    }
    }
    
    function func2() {
  var elem = document.getElementById("thebarofpower");
    var pos = elem.style.top;
    var doneTheStuff;
    var id2 = setInterval(frame2, 10);
    function frame2() {
       if (!doneTheStuff) {
    doneTheStuff = true;
  } else if (pos == 60) {
            clearInterval(id2); 
        } else if (pos > 60) {
            pos++; 
            elem.style.top = pos - 'px';  
        } else {
          pos++;
          elem.style.top = pos + 'px';  
        }
    }
    }
        function func3() {
  var elem = document.getElementById("thebarofpower");
    var pos = elem.style.top;
    var doneTheStuff;
    var id3 = setInterval(frame3, 10);
    function frame3() {
          if (!doneTheStuff) {
    doneTheStuff = true;
  } else if (pos == 120) {
            clearInterval(id3); 
        } else {
            pos++; 
            elem.style.top = pos + 'px';  
        }
    }
    }
```

```css
#button-1 {
  position: absolute;
  background: transparent;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: ;
  box-shadow: 6px 6px 6px #888888;
}
#button-2 {
  position: absolute;
  background: transparent;
  left: 0px;
  top: 60px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: ;
  box-shadow: 6px 6px 6px #888888;
}
#button-3 {
  position: absolute;
  background: transparent;
  left: 0px;
  top: 120px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: ;
  box-shadow: 6px 6px 6px #888888;
}

#thebarofpower{
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #42bff4;
  width: 2px;
  height: 50px;
  left: 70px;
  top: 0px;
  border-radius: 30px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 1px #41d0f4;
}
```

```html
<button id="button-1" onclick="func1()"></button>
<button id="button-2" onclick="func2()"></button>
<button id="button-3" onclick="func3()"></button>
<div id="thebarofpower"></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main issue is that after you change the `style.top` to a number plus `px`, you have to account for that when you check it the next time.  There were also a few situations where you were moving in the wrong direction.

```js
function func1() {
  var elem = document.getElementById("thebarofpower");
  var pos = elem.style.top;
  if (pos[pos.length-2] == "p") pos = pos.slice(0, pos.length -2)
  var doneTheStuff;
  var id = setInterval(frame, 10);

  function frame() {
    if (!doneTheStuff) {
      doneTheStuff = true;
    } else if (pos == 6) {
      clearInterval(id);
    } else if (pos > 6) {
      pos--;
      elem.style.top = pos + 'px';
    } else {
      pos++;
      elem.style.top = pos + 'px';
    }
  }
}

function func2() {
  var elem = document.getElementById("thebarofpower");
  var pos = elem.style.top;
  if (pos[pos.length-2] == "p") pos = pos.slice(0, pos.length -2)
  var doneTheStuff;
  var id2 = setInterval(frame2, 10);

  function frame2() {
    if (!doneTheStuff) {
      doneTheStuff = true;
    } else if (pos == 60) {
      clearInterval(id2);
    } else if (pos > 60) {
      pos--;
      elem.style.top = pos + 'px';
    } else {
      pos++;
      elem.style.top = pos + 'px';
    }
  }
}

function func3() {
  var elem = document.getElementById("thebarofpower");
  var pos = elem.style.top;
  if (pos[pos.length-2] == "p") pos = pos.slice(0, pos.length -2)
  var doneTheStuff;
  var id3 = setInterval(frame3, 10);

  function frame3() {
    if (!doneTheStuff) {
      doneTheStuff = true;
    } else if (pos == 120) {
      clearInterval(id3);
    } else {
      pos++;
      elem.style.top = pos + 'px';
    }
  }
}
```

```css
#button-1 {
  position: absolute;
  background: transparent;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: ;
  box-shadow: 6px 6px 6px #888888;
}

#button-2 {
  position: absolute;
  background: transparent;
  left: 0px;
  top: 60px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: ;
  box-shadow: 6px 6px 6px #888888;
}

#button-3 {
  position: absolute;
  background: transparent;
  left: 0px;
  top: 120px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: ;
  box-shadow: 6px 6px 6px #888888;
}

#thebarofpower {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #42bff4;
  width: 2px;
  height: 50px;
  left: 70px;
  top: 0px;
  border-radius: 30px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 1px #41d0f4;
}
```

```html
<button id="button-1" onclick="func1()"></button>
<button id="button-2" onclick="func2()"></button>
<button id="button-3" onclick="func3()"></button>
<div id="thebarofpower"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

https://jsfiddle.net/t8jztc7x/1/

```js
$('.btn').each(function(){
var btnOffset = $(this).offset().top;
$(this).click(function(){
$('#thebarofpower').css('top',btnOffset)
});
});
```

```css
#button-1 {
  position: absolute;
  background: transparent;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: ;
  box-shadow: 6px 6px 6px #888888;
}
#button-2 {
  position: absolute;
  background: transparent;
  left: 0px;
  top: 60px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: ;
  box-shadow: 6px 6px 6px #888888;
}
#button-3 {
  position: absolute;
  background: transparent;
  left: 0px;
  top: 120px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: ;
  box-shadow: 6px 6px 6px #888888;
}

#thebarofpower{
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #42bff4;
  width: 2px;
  height: 50px;
  left: 70px;
  top: 0px;
  border-radius: 30px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 1px #41d0f4;
 transition:top 0.4s
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="button-1" class="btn"></button>
<button id="button-2" class="btn"></button>
<button id="button-3"  class="btn"></button>
<div id="thebarofpower"></div>
```

Comment: plus thats teleporting, not smooth

Answer (score 1):

Your functions just weren't processing the pixel change exactly right.  I made a couple of small changes (summarized below) and here is a solution that works as intended:

```js
var elem = document.getElementById("thebarofpower");

function func1() {
    var pos = elem.style.top.slice(0,-2);
    var doneTheStuff;
    var id = setInterval(frame, 10);
    function frame() {
        if (!doneTheStuff) {
            doneTheStuff = true;
        }
        else if (pos == 6) {
            clearInterval(id); 
        }
        else if (pos > 6) {
            pos--; 
            elem.style.top = pos + 'px';  
        }
        else {
            pos++;
            elem.style.top = pos + 'px';  
        }
    }
}
    
function func2() {
    var pos = elem.style.top.slice(0,-2);
    var doneTheStuff;
    var id2 = setInterval(frame2, 10);
    function frame2() {
        if (!doneTheStuff) {
            doneTheStuff = true;
        }
        else if (pos == 60) {
            clearInterval(id2); 
        }
        else if (pos > 60) {
            pos--; 
            elem.style.top = pos + 'px';  
        }
        else {
            pos++;
            elem.style.top = pos + 'px';  
        }
    }
}

function func3() {
    var pos = elem.style.top.slice(0,-2);
    var doneTheStuff;
    var id3 = setInterval(frame3, 10);
    function frame3() {
        if (!doneTheStuff) {
            doneTheStuff = true;
        }
        else if (pos == 120) {
            clearInterval(id3); 
        }
        else {
            pos++; 
            elem.style.top = pos + 'px';  
        }
    }
}
```

```css
#button-1 {
  position: absolute;
  background: transparent;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: ;
  box-shadow: 6px 6px 6px #888888;
}
#button-2 {
  position: absolute;
  background: transparent;
  left: 0px;
  top: 60px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: ;
  box-shadow: 6px 6px 6px #888888;
}
#button-3 {
  position: absolute;
  background: transparent;
  left: 0px;
  top: 120px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: ;
  box-shadow: 6px 6px 6px #888888;
}

#thebarofpower{
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #42bff4;
  width: 2px;
  height: 50px;
  left: 70px;
  top: 0px;
  border-radius: 30px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 1px #41d0f4;
}
```

```html
<button id="button-1" onclick="func1()"></button>
<button id="button-2" onclick="func2()"></button>
<button id="button-3" onclick="func3()"></button>
<div id="thebarofpower"></div>
```

Changes:

- Removed "px" from the position before processing it
- Moved the `element` variable declaration outside the functions so you only have to declare it once, rather than 3 times
- Some of the `pos++` commands were moving the bar in the wrong direction; changed them to `pos--`